# Can not promote server to domain controller because required ports are already in use

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a Fresh Windows Server 2012 installation and installed all the Active Directory stuff. Now the Server Manager says that i need to "Promote this server to a domain controller."

[image]

But when i do this i get the following output:

[image]

So it can't use those Ports so i checked the output of netstat :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b | Select-String -Pattern 389

TCP    0.0.0.0:389            WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
TCP    [::]:389               WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
UDP    0.0.0.0:389            *:*
UDP    [::]:389               *:*
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b | Select-String -Pattern 88
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b | Select-String -Pattern 636

TCP    0.0.0.0:636            WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
TCP    [::]:636               WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING


PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b | Select-String -Pattern 3268
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b | Select-String -Pattern 3269
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -a -b

Active Connections


[svchost.exe]
 TCP    0.0.0.0:389            WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING

Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    0.0.0.0:636            WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
[svchost.exe]
 TCP    [::]:389               WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
 TCP    [::]:636               WIN-DM18FTD1NBM:0      LISTENING
[ServerManager.exe]
 UDP    0.0.0.0:389            *:*
[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.exe]
 UDP    [::]:389               *:*
```

So how i do solve this problem so that i can promote it ?

Comment: Nuh uh, this server is not fresh, as you are trying to tell us. You did something to it that broke something. A reinstall is both, the fastest and the most reliable solution

Comment: Maybe we have a different definition of fresh but this server is just a couple of hours old and the only thing i did was installing the AD stuff . Then removed some of the AD stuff because it said i couldn't join a domain with AD Certificate role.
Ok so i will reinstall the server thx.

Comment: You should re-evaluate your definition of fresh. You already saw what happened. By the way, uninstalling the CA roles will never completely remove the data that was created when you configure the CA role. If you already have an AD, you better look for articles on how to remove a CA from an AD.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thx to Daniel i found the issue. 
The Windows Server can't handle some combinations of the Active Directory Roles so i didn't install them(marked in red) i only installed Active Directory Domain Services instead and now it works. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnMgd.png)

In my opinion Windows Server 2012 should print a Warning Message don't use this and this Feature together.

Comment: That 'warning' message is printed in every book and on every technet page about installation and configuration of AD and CA services ;)